# How to make a list from TA-lib results?

Tags: python, polynomials, ta-lib

This is about how to make a usefull list from the last six results from TA-lib moving average.

This is my code for the average:

```
closes_TREND = []
MOVING_AVERAGES = []

klines_TREND = client.get_historical_klines(TRADE_SYMBOL, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR, "20 hours ago UTC")

for data in klines_TREND:
        closes = data[4]
        closes_TREND.append(float(closes))
       
        np_closes_TREND = np.array(closes_TREND)
        moving_average = talib.MA(np_closes_TREND, SMA_PERIOD)
```

gives this result:

```
[nan]
[nan nan]
[nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan nan]
[nan nan nan nan nan nan]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan 
            nan            nan 49083.85571429]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan 
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan 
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143 
 49062.34142857]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan 
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143 
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857 49182.70857143]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857 49182.70857143 49406.18142857]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857 49182.70857143 49406.18142857
 49649.40285714]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857 49182.70857143 49406.18142857
 49649.40285714 49842.8       ]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857 49182.70857143 49406.18142857
 49649.40285714 49842.8        50040.02142857]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857 49182.70857143 49406.18142857
 49649.40285714 49842.8        50040.02142857 50210.48285714]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857 49182.70857143 49406.18142857
 49649.40285714 49842.8        50040.02142857 50210.48285714
 50386.27285714]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857 49182.70857143 49406.18142857
 49649.40285714 49842.8        50040.02142857 50210.48285714
 50386.27285714 50509.12285714]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857 49182.70857143 49406.18142857
 49649.40285714 49842.8        50040.02142857 50210.48285714
 50386.27285714 50509.12285714 50483.18714286]
[           nan            nan            nan            nan
            nan            nan 49083.85571429 49056.04857143
 49062.34142857 49103.36142857 49182.70857143 49406.18142857
 49649.40285714 49842.8        50040.02142857 50210.48285714
 50386.27285714 50509.12285714 50483.18714286 50467.02571429]
```

What i need are te last six values in a list like this:

```
[50040.02, 50210.48, 50386.27, 50509.12, 50483.18, 50467.02]
```

I've tried a lot, this comes closest:

```
test = [round(num, 2) for num in moving_average]
       y  = test[14:]
```

It gives me this:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[50040.02]
[50040.02, 50210.48]
[50040.02, 50210.48, 50386.27]
[50040.02, 50210.48, 50386.27, 50509.12]
[50040.02, 50210.48, 50386.27, 50509.12, 50483.19]
[50040.02, 50210.48, 50386.27, 50509.12, 50483.19, 50467.02]
```

I need the list for a poynomial fit, now i have issues to have the same length in both x and y, probably because of the way the list y is build up.

in de polynomial fit, x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
attempt to get y = [50040.02, 50210.48, 50386.27, 50509.12, 50483.19, 50467.02]

any suggestions?

PS
edited my question to answer the comments.

12-4-21 second edit:

y = test[-6:], gives me this:
It's coming close, but still no good for a polynommial fit.

```
[nan]
[nan, nan]
[nan, nan, nan]
[nan, nan, nan, nan]
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 50058.15]
[nan, nan, nan, nan, 50058.15, 50115.52]
[nan, nan, nan, 50058.15, 50115.52, 50134.18]
[nan, nan, 50058.15, 50115.52, 50134.18, 50205.48]
[nan, 50058.15, 50115.52, 50134.18, 50205.48, 50262.16]
[50058.15, 50115.52, 50134.18, 50205.48, 50262.16, 50257.04]
[50115.52, 50134.18, 50205.48, 50262.16, 50257.04, 50262.79]
[50134.18, 50205.48, 50262.16, 50257.04, 50262.79, 50258.97]
[50205.48, 50262.16, 50257.04, 50262.79, 50258.97, 50317.7]
[50262.16, 50257.04, 50262.79, 50258.97, 50317.7, 50361.69]
[50257.04, 50262.79, 50258.97, 50317.7, 50361.69, 50371.85]
[50262.79, 50258.97, 50317.7, 50361.69, 50371.85, 50463.78]
[50258.97, 50317.7, 50361.69, 50371.85, 50463.78, 50585.92]
[50317.7, 50361.69, 50371.85, 50463.78, 50585.92, 50704.61]
```

`print(type(y[0]))`

gives me this:

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

EDIT 23-4

this is what it prints for x, y and polyn. fit, where i need only the last

```
x = :
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = :
[41676.59, 41223.05, 40937.1, 40708.92, 40627.29, 40770.61]
polyn. fit = :
[ -187.01028571 41458.11904762]
x = :
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = :
[41223.05, 40937.1, 40708.92, 40627.29, 40770.61, 40747.72]
polyn. fit = :
[  -84.50714286 41047.04952381]
x = :
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = :
[40937.1, 40708.92, 40627.29, 40770.61, 40747.72, 40770.06]
polyn. fit = :
[-1.64422857e+01  4.08013890e+04]
x = :
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = :
[40708.92, 40627.29, 40770.61, 40747.72, 40770.06, 41008.3]
polyn. fit = :
[   54.352 40636.27 ]
x = :
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = :
[40627.29, 40770.61, 40747.72, 40770.06, 41008.3, 41136.19]
polyn. fit = :
[   93.71171429 40609.08238095]
x = :
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = :
[40770.61, 40747.72, 40770.06, 41008.3, 41136.19, 41329.56]
polyn. fit = :
[  119.95428571 40660.52095238]
x = :
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = :
[40747.72, 40770.06, 41008.3, 41136.19, 41329.56, 41339.63]
polyn. fit = :
[  136.16971429 40714.81904762]
x = :
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = :
[40770.06, 41008.3, 41136.19, 41329.56, 41339.63, 41358.35]
polyn. fit = :
[  117.966 40862.1  ]
x = :
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y = :
[41008.3, 41136.19, 41329.56, 41339.63, 41358.35, 41526.3]
polyn. fit = :
[   93.33 41049.73] #>> this is the correct value!
```

Everytime it executes i get al these values, over and over...

Comment: What's the complete code the `client.get_historical_klines` function call? I notice it is clipped out. It might be easier for us to test if it is given

Comment: edited my question, complete klines,  y = a list

Comment: Have you tried setting `y` to `y = [x[-1] for x in test[-6:]]` instead of `y  = test[14:]`?

Comment: It gives an error: IndexError: Invalid index to scalar variable

Comment: Does `y = test[-6:]` work? If it does, could try adding the line `print(type(y[0]))`? What does it output?

Comment: editted question with results

Comment: I think your `y` is getting the right result when setting it to be `y = test[-6:]`. It's just that you're continuously printing so it looks like a list of lists but instead it is just a list of numbers that is continuously updated, with the final version being `[50317.7, 50361.69, 50371.85, 50463.78, 50585.92, 50704.61]`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response. I think since `moving_average` doesn't always return an numpy array with length of 6, you need to have an if statement to check when length of `y` is equal 6 before proceeding. You should also consider adding the line `moving_average = moving_average[~np.isnan(moving_average)]` to remove `nan` values in `moving_average` so that `y` doesn't have any nan values in its list.

```
closes_TREND = []
MOVING_AVERAGES = []

klines_TREND = client.get_historical_klines("BTCUSDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR, "20 hours ago UTC")

for data in klines_TREND:
    closes = data[4]
    closes_TREND.append(float(closes))

    np_closes_TREND = np.array(closes_TREND)
    SMA_PERIOD = 3
    moving_average = talib.MA(np_closes_TREND, SMA_PERIOD)
    # Filter out nan values in bumpy array
    moving_average = moving_average[~np.isnan(moving_average)]
    test = [round(num, 2) for num in moving_average]
    y = test[-6:]
    if len(y) == 6:
        print(y)
        # Perform de polynomial fit here
```

Edit: If you only need to get the last list, you can move the `if` statement outside of the `for` loop so that it will only perform polynomial fit once for the last `y` list

```
closes_TREND = []
MOVING_AVERAGES = []

klines_TREND = client.get_historical_klines("BTCUSDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR, "20 hours ago UTC")

for data in klines_TREND:
    closes = data[4]
    closes_TREND.append(float(closes))

    np_closes_TREND = np.array(closes_TREND)
    SMA_PERIOD = 3
    moving_average = talib.MA(np_closes_TREND, SMA_PERIOD)
    # Filter out nan values in bumpy array
    moving_average = moving_average[~np.isnan(moving_average)]
    test = [round(num, 2) for num in moving_average]
    y = test[-6:]

if len(y) == 6:
    print(y)
    # Perform de polynomial fit here
```

Comment: This is it! thanks!! (it still prints several times, but the polynomial fit works just fine this time)

Comment: Still struggling a bit, the polynomial fit works, but i'm having trouble with the fact the list is printed several times with different numbers. I thought it would build up in a way where only the last value is updated, but that is not the fact. When i let the function execute i get seven lists, so i als get seven polynomial fits, where i need only the last. I updated my question with a print of the lists and the polynomial fits. Does anyone know how to get only the last list or only the last polynomial fit?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. Does that give the result you expected?

Comment: Did not expect this to happen, i thought the previous lists also equals the length 6, but it turned out excactly the way i wanted. Thanx for your help!